# RTK Query running twice instead of once

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is an authorizaton middleware component that wraps the App component in a React app using Redux Toolkit.
The authorization is done using an `access_token` cookie. There is a also a `logged_in` cookie with `httponly=false` so the client knows its logged in, and a `refresh_token` cookie.

The logic is:

- 1. check if there is a `logged_in` cookie, if not, finish
- 2. send a request to the `GetWhoAmI` api endpoint

  - `GetWhoAmI` success: finish
- 3. `GetWhoAmI` fail: try to refresh the `access_token` using the `RefreshToken` endpoint

  - `RefreshToken` fail: delete the `logged_in` cookie and finish
- 4. `RefreshToken` success: try the `GetWhoAmI` endpoint again

  - `GetWhoAmI` success: finish
  - `GetWhoAmI` fail: remove `logged_in` cookie and finish

I do not like this state machine approach, but I have tried everything else and I kept getting strange loops, or queries not running at all.

```
export const AuthMiddleware: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactElement }> = 
    ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);
  const [cookie, , removeCookie] = useCookies(["logged_in"]);
  const hasLoggedInCookie = cookie.logged_in === "true";

  const { isSuccess: whoAmISuccess, isError: whoAmIError } = 
    useGetWhoAmIQuery(undefined, { skip: state !== 2 && state !== 4 });
  const { isSuccess: refreshSuccess, isError: refreshError } = 
    useRefreshTokenQuery(undefined, { skip: state !== 3 });

  if (state === 1) {
    setState(hasLoggedInCookie ? 2 : 0);
  }
  if (state === 2 && whoAmIError) setState(3);
  if (state === 2 && whoAmISuccess) setState(0);
  if (state === 4 && whoAmISuccess) setState(0);
  if (state === 4 && whoAmIError) {
    removeCookie("logged_in");
    setState(0);
  }
  if (state === 3 && refreshError) {
    removeCookie("logged_in");
    setState(0);
  }
  if (state === 3 && refreshSuccess) {
    setState(4);
  }

  console.log(state);
  if (state !== 0) {
    return <FullScreenLoader />;
  }
  return children;
};
```

As far as functionality goes this works, but there are two strange issues:

1. When it gets to the point where the `RefreshToken` endpoint needs to be invoked, the endpoint is queried twice in a row.
   [image: refresh endpoint queried twice]
2. If I log the state, it looks as the state goes backwards sometime, for example it goes 3-2-3 or 4-3-4, even though from the code it is not possible for the state to go from 4 to 3 or from 3 to 2.

There is obviously something I'm doing wrong here but after two days of banging my head against this problem I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a refresh token approach in the documentation that lives in RTK Query, not in a component - have you tried that?

[Automatic Reauthorization by extending fetchBaseQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)

Your code would come down to a single `useGetWhoAmIQuery()` call.

Also, something like a token refresh (if you choose this approach here) should always be a mutation, not a query. Then it could also invalidate the `getWhoAmIQuery` and it could automatically refetch - no need for you to orchestrate that!

Comment: How would I delete the cookie with this approach? I can't use the useCookies hook inside the query.

Comment: Why would you read, set or delete a cookie from the client? That's the server's job. You should be using a `httpOnly` cookie and the client should not even be able to access it at all due to security reasons.
=> If you want to delete a cookie, make a (mutation) request to `/logout` (or delete it in your other endpoints if access fails)

Comment: I have a `logged_in` cookie with the contents of `true` set to `httponly=false`. So the client knows in the absence of this cookie it shouldn't even attempt the whoAmI endpoint. But if the refresh endpoint fails with 401 (eg. refresh token expired) this cookie needs to be deleted from the client. I guess I could remove this cookie but then every load will trigger a whoAmI request.

Comment: That one request will hurt you a lot less than trying to make it work correctly. You'll still have to handle lots of cases where that cookie is present but the user is logged out due to various reasons. Your server will handle lots of requests anyways, that cheap one extra request won't hurt ;)

Comment: Do I need to put this refresh logic inside every single endpoint query? Eg. access_token expires while the user is using the app, he clicks on some protected resouce and it returns 401, now automatic refresh should be applied. Is there some kind of global interceptor I can use that will attempt refresh if any of the endpoints retuns 401?

Comment: the `baseQuery` is your "global interceptor" for all requests and since you should only have one single api in your app, you only need to declare that once.